# Excel conditional scale colors based on another value across split cells

Tags: excel, colors, formatting, conditional-statements, scale

Hi I have a problem I am struggling with.

I am trying to create a sliding scale of colors for the cells in individual row based on the corresponding value for the same row in column A.

For example:

In row one the cell colors for cells C1:E1,G1:J1 should be based on the value in A1 and the corresponding color from the color chart

In row two the cell colors for cells C2:E2,G2:J2 should be based on the value in A2 and the corresponding color from the color chart
This should continue down for all rows (about 500 rows)

Before Image

[image]

Example After Image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use a secondary table with values which correspond to the colour scale. Then you apply conditional formatting on original tables, but using the value from the secondary table. It is simple and it doesn't requires macros, but you need a secondary table (and so space for it).

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub ApplyConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet here
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    For rw = 3 To 8 ' change to your respective rows
        With ws
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(rw, "E"), .Cells(rw, "K")) ' change to your respective columns

            With rng
                .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority  ' now its index is 1, in case there already was cond formatting applied
            End With

            With rng.FormatConditions(1)
                With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                    .Value = 0
                    .FormatColor.Color = 7039480
                End With

                With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Value = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$D$" & rw & "*3" ' References column D, change as needed
                    .FormatColor.Color = 8711167
                End With

                With .ColorScaleCriteria(3)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Value = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$D$" & rw & "*5" ' References column D, change as needed
                    .FormatColor.Color = 8109667
                End With
            End With
        End With
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give some more explanation and what are those colour values?

Comment: We usually want some comments, not just the solution. We hope that people will try to understand the problem and the solution, instead of just blind copying answers.